# Case_when or if else?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, if-statement, case

I have a dataset like this with the column "value":

[image]

I want to create with R the column "code", meaning that:

- Values: between 0.0 to 0.3 --> code: 1
- Values: between 0.40 to 0.50 --> code: 2
- Values: >50 --> code: 3

What should I use instead of case_when (which for my knowledge works only for two conditions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `case_when()` function handles multiple conditions, whereas `ifelse()` handles only one (unless you chain calls).  You may use `case_when` here:

```r
df$code <- case_when(
    df$value >= 0.0 & df$value <= 0.3 ~ 1,
    df$value > 0.4 & df$value <= 0.5 ~ 2,
    df$value > 0.5 ~ 3
)
```